# vtk msvc14 installation fails when building INSTALL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, vtk

I have successfully built the VTK libraries: using the cmake configure and generate, plus the building in release and debug of the msvc 14 solution. More precisely I was able to build the `ALL BUILD` project. But when it comes to building the `INSTALL` project it fails.

the error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   MSB3073 The command

```
"setlocal
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd"
```

> exited with code 1.   INSTALL C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  133

How can I either debug this problem or shortcut the msvc INSTALL build step?

I am working on windows7 using microsoft visual studio 14 2015.

Comment: In my experience this is usually because it's trying to install to a location requiring admin priviledges - try running visual studio as administrator.

Comment: Thanks @JonnyPaton, that was the issue. Can I mark your comment as an aswer?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'll add an answer with a bit more detail shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error commonly happens because the default cmake install location requires admin privileges (normally C:/Program Files/).

There are two simple ways around this:

1. Run visual studio as Administrator
2. Override the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable to point somewhere not requiring admin privileges

Personally, I'd recommend the second option (When configuring cmake, the command would be something like: `cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:/Some/Path`)